# Errors in using Turkish characters despite using relevant codes and packages

Tags: utf-8, latex

I am trying to use Turkish characters in the reference part of my document written in the LateX environment but I get these errors:
LaTeX Error: Invalid UTF-8 byte "9D.
Undefined control sequence.
LaTeX Error: Invalid UTF-8 byte "80.

I also tried adding `\usepackage[turkish]{babel}\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` to my document but it still does not work. Can anyone tell me how I can solve this? I am copying the relevant part of my code here:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
here comes the body of my document\\
.\\.\\.\\.\\


\begin{thebibliography}{}
\bibitem {kadiOglu}
Kad{\i}o\u{g}lu, M., K\”{o}se, A., & Tun\c{c}, M.: Icing warning systems that can notify icing 3 hours ahead on highways. In 5th ATMOSPHERIC SCIENCE SYMPOSIUM, Volume 621, (pp. 505–511) (2011).
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please make a compilable [mre]

Comment: I edited the code to compilable minimal reproducible examples you wanted @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two and a half problems:

- you can't directly use `&`. This letter is reserved to be used as alignment character in table cells. If you want to use it in text, you have to escape it `\&`
- The macro `\”` does not exist. Did you mean to write `\"` instead?
- don't abuse `\\` for line breaks. This should only be used in tabulars and similar environments.
- (if your tex distribution is reasonable up-to-date, you don't need `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`, that's the default sinec a couple of years)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
here comes the body of my document


\begin{thebibliography}{1}
\bibitem {kadiOglu}
Kad{\i}o\u{g}lu, M., K\"{o}se, A., \& Tun\c{c}, M.: Icing warning systems that can notify icing 3 hours ahead on highways. In 5th ATMOSPHERIC SCIENCE SYMPOSIUM, Volume 621, (pp. 505–511) (2011).
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes I changed \” to \" and it worked. Thank you so much:)